# Invalid Memory Access when calling Delphi method via JNA

Tags: java, delphi, jna

I am attempting to call the following Delphi method:

> [image]

However, I get this exception:

> [image]

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //解决中文乱码a
    System.setProperty("jna.encoding", "GBK");  
    byte[] b = FileUtil.file2ByteArray("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/jyp/dll/钻孔检验批质量验收记录表.LIL");
    System.out.println(b);
    String nn = "llllllllllll";

    //System.out.println(testdll.Instance.PBF_RepToPDF_File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/jyp/dll/1啊.LIL","C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/jyp/dll/1_File.PDF" ));
    //JYP_TK_ReportDLL.Instance.PBF_RepToPDF_File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/jyp/dll/1啊.LIL","C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/jyp/dll/1_File.PDF" );
    JYP_TK_ReportDLL.Instance.PBF_RepToPDF_Stream("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/jyp/dll/1.PDF",nn);
    //JYP_TK_ReportDLL.Instance.PBF_RepToJPG_File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/jyp/dll/1啊.LIL","C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/jyp/dll/1_File.JPG" );
}

public interface JYP_TK_ReportDLL extends Library {
    JYP_TK_ReportDLL Instance = (JYP_TK_ReportDLL) Native.loadLibrary("JYP_TK_ReportDLL",
            JYP_TK_ReportDLL.class);

    boolean PBF_RepToPDF_Stream(String SaveFile, String arr);
    boolean PBF_RepToPDF_File(String SourceFile, String  SaveFile);
    boolean PBF_RepToJPG_File(String SourceFile, String  SaveFile);
}
```

Comment: Remember to extend from `StdCallLibrary`, not `Library`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not readily possible to call that method from a non Delphi module. The second parameter is a Delphi native dynamic array. You can't directly make one of those from your Java module.

Contact the vendor and request a library that is amenable to use from languages other than Delphi. That would require the dynamic array to be replaced by two arguments. The length of the array, and the address of the start of the array.

If that is not possible you will need to write an adapter module in Delphi.

Comment: so I solve this problem  thanks , the Delphi TByteDynArray --->JAVA byte[]